# MySQL sum with multiple table

Tags: mysql

i have three tables which.

```
result: result_id, person_id, result
area: person_id, district_id
district:  province_id, district_id
```

I want `SUM(result.result) GROUP BY province_id`

But since `area.person_id` have multiple `person_id` so when I `SUM(result.result)` i alway got double result or triple value acroding to how many there are in `area.person_id`.

Could you help.

Comment: Can you provide an SQL fiddle please?

Comment: Split it into multiple queries. There is no real reason to put everything into a single query all the time.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery with `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates.

```
SELECT province_id, SUM(result)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT d.province_id, r.person_id
  FROM result AS r
  JOIN area AS a ON r.person_id = a.person_id
  JOIN district AS d ON a.district_id = d.district_id) AS p
JOIN result AS r ON p.person_id = r.person_id
GROUP BY province_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6de4d0/13)

Comment: it look don't have province_id in area. it has only district_id

Comment: I'm joining with `district` to get `province_id`.

Comment: Please make a sqlfiddle. I can't put a screen grab in a database.

Comment: Also, post the input data and desired results in your question.

Comment: as you can see from my table: I want SUM(expectedSE) and Group by dist_code.pro_id through san_fss_areas.fs_id

Comment: Until you create a sqlfiddle, I will ignore this question.